# Get named Vector values with non-unique names

Tags: r, vector

I have this named vector and I want to retrieve certain elements

```
a <-c(1,2,3,4)
names(a) <- c("a", "b", "a", "b")
```

But when I try to get all the values with the name `"a"` I only get the number 1 and I want number 1 and 3

```
> a["a"]
a 
1
```

Comment: like that : a[names(a)=="a"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to droopy!

```
a[names(a)=="a"]
```